# String regex two mismatches Python

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

How can I extend the code below to allow me to explore all instances where I have 2 mismatches or less between my substring and the parent string?

Substring: `SSQP`

String-to-match-to: `SSPQQQQPSSSSQQQSSQPSPSQSSQPSSQPPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQ`

Here is an example where only one possible mismatch is incorporated:

```
>>> s = 'SSPQQQQPSSSSQQQSSQPSPSQSSQPSSQPPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQ'
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(SSQP|[A-Z]SQP|S[A-Z]QP|SS[A-Z]P|SSQ[A-Z]))', s)
['SSQQ', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SSQP']
```

Obviously, incorporating the *possibility* of two mismatches in the code above would require a lot of brute-force typing of all the possible combinations.

How can I extend this code (or refactor this code) to explore the possibility of two mismatches?

Furthermore, I want to modify my output so that I get the numeric index returned (not `SSQQ` or `SSQP`) of the exact position the substring matched the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `re` here you can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) module instead and save a lot of memory.

You can first extract all sub-strings with length 4 then compare them with your `substring` and just select those that have less that 2 difference with your `substring` :

```
from itertools import izip,islice,tee

def sub_findre(s,substring,diffnumber):
    sublen=len(substring)
    zip_gen=(izip(substring,islice(s,i,i+sublen)) for i in xrange(len(s)))
    for z in zip_gen:
        l,z=tee(z)
        if sum(1 for i,j in l if i==j)>=sublen-diffnumber:
            new=izip(*z)
            next(new)
            yield ''.join(next(new))
```

Demo:

```
s='SSPQQQQPSSSSQQQSSQPSPSQSSQPSSQPPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQSSQPSSSSQPSPSQ'

substring='SSQP'
print list(sub_findre(s,substring,2))

['SSPQ', 'SPQQ', 'QQQP', 'SSSS', 'SSSQ', 'SSQQ', 'SQQQ', 'SSQP', 'PSQS', 'SSQP', 'SSQP', 'SQPP', 'SSSS', 'SSSQ', 'SSQP', 'PSQS', 'SSQP', 'SSSS', 'SSSQ', 'SSQP', 'PSQS', 'SSQP', 'SSSS', 'SSSQ', 'SSQP', 'PSQ']
```

If you want to return the indices you need to put the indices in `izip` which you can use `itertools.repeat()` to repeat the index with the length of `substring` :

```
from itertools import izip,islice,tee,repeat

def sub_findre(s,substring,diffnumber):
    sublen=len(substring)
    zip_gen=(izip(substring,islice(s,i,i+sublen),repeat(i,sublen)) for i in xrange(len(s)))
    for z in zip_gen:
        l,z=tee(z)
        if sum(1 for i,j,_ in l if i==j)>=sublen-diffnumber:
            new=izip(*z)
            next(new)
            next(new)
            yield next(new)[0]
```

Demo:

```
print list(sub_findre(s,substring,2))
[0, 1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 20, 23, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34, 39, 42, 46, 47, 48, 53, 56, 60, 61, 62, 67]
```

Comment: Indeed, regular expressions are just the wrong tool to use altogether. For 2 mistakes out of 20, there would be 190 alternates in the pattern.

Comment: Can you return index numbers, similar to `match.start(0)` technique of 200_success?

Comment: @Kasra Accepted!  Do you mind if in the next few days I upload an algorithm I'm currently developing to solve this problem as well?  I think I may have an alternate solution using a different technique than the very interesting technique you use here.

Comment: @warship mm Ok, i'll try ;) but still i think may answer can be optimized,using generators is very efficient way in terms of memory use, although its very faster than regex, I think using a data structure like dictionary can be better since it use hash-table and you can get more speed from.

Comment: @Kasra Cool!  If I figure out something interesting as well or an alternative approach, I will post my solution as an answer and you can evaluate it and let me know what you think :-)

Comment: @warship Sure! just tag me!;)

Answer (score 3):

The combinatorial explosion is not *that* bad for two mismatches out of four.

First, observe that you can omit `SSQP` itself, since it's covered by all of the more lenient cases.

```
re.findall(r'(?=([A-Z]SQP|S[A-Z]QP|SS[A-Z]P|SSQ[A-Z]))', s)
```

So, the number of cases is

```
               4!
C(4, 1) = ––––––––––––– = 4
          1! * (4 - 1)!
```

For up to two mismatches, the number of cases is

```
               4!
C(4, 2) = ––––––––––––– = 6
          2! * (4 - 2)!
```

Namely,

```
re.findall('(?=(SS..|S.Q.|S..P|.SQ.|.S.P|..QP))', s)
```

(To simplify the illustration, I've taken the liberty of writing `.` instead of `[A-Z]`.)

---

To get the positions of the matches instead of the text of the matches:

```
[match.start(0) for match in re.finditer('(?=(SS..|S.Q.|S..P|.SQ.|.S.P|..QP))', s)]
```

Comment: I see what you're doing, but I have substrings as large as 10 sometimes 20 letters, sometimes more, it's very hard for me to scale using the `re` module.  Perhaps there is something else I can use besides for regular expressions?  I like your wording of "combinatorial explosion" though, I will put that terminology in my arsenal :-)

Comment: Then why did you ask the question for C(4,2) instead of what you actually wanted? How many mistakes out of 20 are you talking about?

Comment: 0, 1, or 2 mistakes in a substring of length 20 are possible.  Writing such a thing out combinatorially is a royal pain.  In the OP, I simply wanted to provide a MWE.