# Returning sequences with two mismatches from original string

Tags: python, string, function, search

I am looking for some code to return all sequences with two mismatches from the original string, for the purposes of finding parts of a protein sequence that are similar to the original sequence I input. For example, searching for LKLD in LELFLKEF should return: 
LELF
LKEF
LFLK
I have looked at various python approaches to do this, but I can't seem to make any work.

[Search for string allowing for one mismatch in any location of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420412/search-for-string-allowing-for-one-mismatch-in-any-location-of-the-string)

[String regex two mismatches Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365168/string-regex-two-mismatches-python)

[Ambiguous substring with mismatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355841/ambiguous-substring-with-mismatches)

Comment: Does order matter? Would LKLD in DLLKFA return LKFA and DLLK (all the letters in a dif order).

Comment: Yes, the order of the letters matters. DLLK would not work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to roll through the sequence and calculate [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) for each alignment of the query 'LKLD' to the subject sequence 'LELFLKEF'. There is a sample implementation of hamming distance calculation in the linked wikipedia article. Once you have that your code would do something like:

```
# hamming distance
d = lambda s1, s2: sum(e1 != e2 for e1, e2 in zip(s1, s2))

subject = 'LELFLKEF'
query = 'LKLD'
for i in range(len(subject)-len(query)+1):
    aligned_subject = subject[i:i+len(query)]
    if d(aligned_subject, query) == 2:
         print(aligned_subject)
```

Output:

```
LELF
LFLK
LKEF
```

Note that this is a bit of a naive solution with plenty of room for optimization, but it will work for simple cases and reasonably small strings. A condensed version that produces a list:

```
s='LELFLKEF'
q='LKLD'
d= lambda s1, s2: sum(e1 != e2 for e1, e2 in zip(s1, s2))
[s[i:i+len(q)] for i in range(len(s)-len(q)+1) if d(s[i:i+len(q)],q) == 2]
```

The `for` loop rolls through all possible ungapped alignments of your two strings:

```
0
LELFLKEF
||||
LKLD
 1
LELFLKEF
 ||||
 LKLD
  2
LELFLKEF
  ||||
  LKLD
   3
LELFLKEF
   ||||
   LKLD
    4
LELFLKEF
    ||||
    LKLD
```

There are also many implementations for the problem of [alignment of biological sequences](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.pairwise2-module.html) so you might also want to explore some more involved techniques that handle things like gapped alignment and [more complicated modeling of substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOSUM)

Comment: Your code appears to ignore the order of the letters: it gives results like ELFL, which is indeed two letters different from the original sequence, but four letters different if you look at what positions they are.

Comment: i was printing out all comparisons to illustrate, its easy enough to filter by distance == 2 but I will edit